# XGBoost regression predicts constant values

Tags: python, scikit-learn, xgboost

I am trying to use XGBoost to predict the number of incoming calls.

My `df` looks like this and has 1152 rows:

|  | x | calls |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 8154.0 |
| 1 | 1 | 8526.0 |
| 2 | 2 | 8088.0 |
| 3 | 3 | 7044.0 |
| 4 | 4 | 7236.0 |
| 5 | 5 | 6492.0 |

This is my code:

```
import xgboost
from xgboost import XGBRegressor
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('sickness_table Kopie.csv', index_col=None)
X = df.x.values.reshape(-1,1)
y = df.calls

def train_test_split(data, n_test):
    return data[:n_test], data[n_test:]

# because of time series data, I am splitting manually so the data doesn't shuffle
x_train, x_test = train_test_split(X, 921)
y_train, y_test = train_test_split(y, 921)

model = XGBRegressor()
model.fit(x_train, y_train)

pred = model.predict(x_test)
```

When I `print(pred)` it looks like this:

```
[9044.7, 9044.7, 9044.7, 9044.7, 9044.7, 9044.7, 9044.7 .... ]
```

The same happens with Random Forest. I tried playing around with some parameters, then the value changes but the numbers are the same for every prediction.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it possible for you to share your csv file? Because if your csv is like your input dataframe, it's not possible to predict something coherent. ML is not a magical tool. If you have no feature that describe your data, how do you want to predict values?

Comment: In the sample of df that you show, the columns are 'x' and 'y'. In your code, you refer to them as 'x' and 'calls'. Does it help to replace 'y = df.calls' -> 'y = f.y.values.reshape(-1,1)'?

Comment: Here is my csv: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QUVmVfluMJ57hR1mkF2BR7ksPxkwZMiQ_5V4DzJ6K90/edit?usp=sharing

And thanks for pointing out the calls/y-confusion. I made a mistake there - 'calls' is correct. I'll correct that.

Comment: I check your data. In this state it is not possible to do much. What `x` means?

Comment: 'x' is quasi an index. Actually I had a column 'date' - but I threw it out, because I could not have used it as input for my model.
What could I do with this "narrow" data set instead? Simple regression?

Comment: The data in the CSV file seems to have a seasonal pattern, so if you put back the dates you can extract some time-related features (e.g. hour of the day, day of the week, month of the year) and use them in the model.

Comment: Thank you! I will definitely check this out.

Comment: Update: I tried that and it worked - thank you all! :)